# I want to change name on uploaded images

Tags: php, image, gallery

I want to change name on uploaded images.  Here is my php code. I am doing a simple ecommerce website.
If someone can help me how i can add code to change name of images and save them on my database.
Thank you!

```
 /*
 * Upload files.
 */
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    if (isset($_FILES['file']['error'])) {
        foreach ($_FILES['file']['error'] as $uploadedFileKey => $uploadedFileError) {
            if ($uploadedFileError === UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE) {
                $errors[] = 'You did not provide any files.';
            } elseif ($uploadedFileError === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                $uploadedFileName = basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$uploadedFileKey]);

                if ($_FILES['file']['size'][$uploadedFileKey] <= UPLOAD_MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
                    $uploadedFileType = $_FILES['file']['type'][$uploadedFileKey];
                    $uploadedFileTempName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$uploadedFileKey];

                    $uploadedFilePath = rtrim(UPLOAD_DIR, '/') . '/' . $uploadedFileName;

                    if (in_array($uploadedFileType, $allowedMimeTypes)) {
                        if (!move_uploaded_file($uploadedFileTempName, $uploadedFilePath)) {
                            $errors[] = 'The file "' . $uploadedFileName . '" could not be uploaded.';
                        } else {
                            $filenamesToSave[] = $uploadedFilePath;
                        }
                    } else {
                        $errors[] = 'The extension of the file "' . $uploadedFileName . '" is not valid. Allowed extensions: JPG, JPEG, PNG, or GIF.';
                    }
                } else {
                    $errors[] = 'The size of the file "' . $uploadedFileName . '" must be of max. ' . (UPLOAD_MAX_FILE_SIZE / 10240) . ' KB';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: This is also a bit unclear, to which name/naming convention do you want to rename them?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the $uploadedFileName var and set it to the value you want for the name, as you can see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) the second argument of the move_uploaded_file function is the destination, there you need to put the new name.

Please check [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php#111412) for some security guidance on the file name.